# Get all key combinations from nested maps

Tags: scala

I have a nested map like so:

```
val m: Map[Int, Map[String, Seq[Int]]] = 
  Map(
    1 -> Map(
      "A" -> Seq(1, 2, 3),
      "B" -> Seq(4, 5, 6)
    ),
    2 -> Map(
      "C" -> Seq(7, 8, 9),
      "D" -> Seq(10, 11, 12),
      "E" -> Seq(13, 14, 15)
    ),
    3 -> Map(
      "F" -> Seq(16, 17, 18)
    )
  )
```

I want the desired output to show every possible combination of the integers in the Seqs. For example:

```
List((1, "A", 1),
     (1, "A", 2),
     (1, "A", 3),
     (1, "B", 4),
     (1, "B", 5),
     (1, "B", 6),
     (2, "C", 7),
     (2, "C", 8),
     (2, "C", 9),
     (2, "D", 10),
     (2, "D", 11),
     (2, "D", 12),
     (2, "E", 13),
     (2, "E", 14),
     (2, "E", 15),
     (3, "F", 16),
     (3, "F", 17),
     (3, "F", 18))
```

I have been trying different combinations of map and flatMap, but nothing has been working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a possibility using a for comprehension:

```
for {
  (k1, v1) <- m
  (k2, v2) <- v1
  v3 <- v2
} yield (k1, k2, v3)
```

This goes through all top key/value pairs of m. For each of these top values, this goes through all nested key/values. And finally for all of these nested values (which are the lists), it goes through each elements and yields what's requested.

A for comprehension is an equivalent to nested `flatMap`s, such as:

```
m.flatMap{
  case (k1, v1) => v1.flatMap {
    case (k2, v2) => v2.map(v3 => (k1, k2, v3))
  }
}
```